# Uninstalling software

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I installed SAOImage DS9  months ago, it is a software for image analysis.

Now I want to uninstall it but it can't be found, I run

```
sudo apt-get remove DS9
sudo apt-get remove SAOImageDS9
```

or I try to open it via the terminal by just "DS9" or so and it can't be found, still when i search it in the menu I can find it and even open it.

Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you installed it.

1. If you installed it using apt, you can uninstall it using `$ sudo apt remove <PACKAGE>` command.
   Also if you dont know the package name, its possible to find it using `$ dpkg --list | grep ds9` (replace *ds9* with some other possible keywords)
2. If you installed it from published source, you can read the *README* of project. usually there's a something about *Uninstall*.

**PS:** According to official tar.gz of project (downloaded from [here](http://ds9.si.edu/site/Download.html)), it seems no installation instruction required, and if so, no uninstallation required too! just delete downloaded file.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the packages list and uninstalled it.